# "No qualifying bean of type" while using autowired in JPA Repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to create a REST Service using Spring Boot and I'm having problems using `@Autowired` between Service and Repositories.

EDIT AFTER ANSWERS:

This is my code:

Entity

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name= Constants.USERS, schema = Constants.SCHEMA)
public class Users {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;   //<----like this
    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "lastname", nullable = false)
    private String lastname;

    public Users() {
    }

    public Users(String username, String lastname) {
        this.username = username;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

}
```

Repository

```
   import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<Users,Integer> {

    public List<Users> findAll();
    public long count(); // and no need to define function here
}
```

Service

```
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class UsersService{

    private UsersRepository usersRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UsersService(UsersRepository usersRepository) {
        this.usersRepository = usersRepository;
    }


    public long count() {
        long conteggio = usersRepository.count();
        return conteggio;
    }
}
```

This is the traceback

```
Error creating bean with name 'usersService' .Unsatisfied dependency expressed through 
constructor paramet
er 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.repository.UsersRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}.
No qualifying bean of type 'com.intesasanpaolo.dsi.core.bear.ptrm0.connector.jpa.UsersRepository' available:
```

expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Comment: Move `@Autowired` from the attribute to the ctor in `UsersService`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you do not have any primary key in your User table.

JPA requires that every entity has an ID. So no, entity w/o an ID is not allowed. Try adding a primary key of type Integer as it is required when extending to the JPa repository as the second argument passed is the type of primary key. You can define a field as primary key by using `@Id` annotation. You can do something like below:

```
package com.model;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name=Constants.USERS, schema = Constants.SCHEMA)
public class Users {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private int id;   //<----like this
@Column(name= "username", nullable=false)
private String username;

@Column(name="lastname", nullable = false)
private String lastname;

public Users() {
}

public Users(String username, String lastname) {
    this.username = username;
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}
```

}

Keep your repository same

Also , you do not have to write @Autowire on the field as the constructor will automatically inject the bean to the field

```
@Autowired   // this is not necessary you can remove this too
    private final UsersRepository usersRepository;

    public UsersService(UsersRepository usersRepository) {
        this.usersRepository = usersRepository;
    }
```

Also, I think you should be extending to JpaRepository like below instead of JpaConnector

```
@Repository
public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<Users,Integer> {

    public List<Users> findAll();
    public long count(); // and no need to define function here
}
```

Comment: Replicated this code but same mistake:  No qualifying bean of type 'com.repository.UsersRepository' available:
 expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Comment: Could you should the code where you are injecting this UserService bean
Also, Have you changed the name JpaConnector to JpaRepository like above.

Comment: Also, try rebuilding or recompiling the project after the changes

Comment: I edited my question with the new code. I tried to remove the Autowired from the constructor (same problem) or to remove the constructor. In this last case, I had NullPointerException on usersRepository variable

Comment: Could you post your controller class too

Comment: Where you used userservice dependency as it seems there is some issue there too

Comment: I did not implemented RestController yet, could it be a problem?

Comment: No that should not be a problem could you show the directory structure of your project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248786/discussion-between-sumit-and-luigi105).

Answer (score 0):

```
    public UsersService(UsersRepository usersRepository) {
        this.usersRepository = usersRepository;
    }
```

try removing this contructor

Comment: If I remove the constructor, I've this compilation error: "Variable 'usersRepository' might not have been initialized"

Comment: have you tried extending JPArepository rather than JPAconnector?

Comment: yes. In this case, I've runtime error NullPointerException because "usersRepository" is null

Comment: are you sure that all your controller,service,repository package are in single springboot package like this  [spring-boot strucuture](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmedium.com%2Fthe-resonant-web%2Fspring-boot-2-0-project-structure-and-best-practices-part-2-7137bdcba7d3&psig=AOvVaw2aF0JqmsVEMX6CFl7oDeUp&ust=1665767538531000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAwQjRxqFwoTCIjWqObZ3foCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAS)

Comment: Yes, they are in the same package

Answer (score 0):

You might need to specify the @EnableJpaRepository in your app, something like this:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
... 

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class MyApplication {
    ...
}
```